# Failure to find javax.annotation:com.springsource.javax.annotation:jar:1.0.0

Tags: java, spring, maven, annotations

I'm getting this error when I build my project (I think it's coming from Guice version 2.0).  Does anyone know which repository `javax.annotation:com.springsource.javax.annotation:jar:1.0.0` comes from?  I've googled and have been unable to find anything.  Rather than "the springsource repository" I'd like an actual, working url.

I have put this in my pom:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>       
  <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.annotation</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0.0</version>     
</dependency>
```

EDIT: This is *not* the same question as [How do I get Eclipse and Maven to download the JARs I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852191/how-do-i-get-eclipse-and-maven-to-download-the-jars-i-need) because that answer does not help me.  When I use that solution I am still getting my error.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say that it's a possible duplicate?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I saw that question but the solution to it isn't related to the solution to mine.

Comment: I've reopened it and updated my post. I hope this helps.

Comment: I've reupdated it to download using the Maven POM instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow a link from the SpringSource page that Buhake Sindi provided downloading the JAR, it will redirect you to a following location:

http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/javax.annotation/com.springsource.javax.annotation/1.0.0/com.springsource.javax.annotation-1.0.0.jar

From this I deducted it might be a working repository, so I configured one like this:

```
    <repository>
        <id>springsource-external</id>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external</url>
    </repository>
```

**and it worked** - try it out. It's weird because it's an ivy repo, the maven one should also work according to FAQ, but it seems something is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Maven, try add the dependency as shown by [SpringSource](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.javax.annotation&version=1.0.0):

```
<dependency> 
     <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>       
     <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.annotation</artifactId>  
     <version>1.0.0</version>     
</dependency>
```

Based on the [FAQ](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/faq#q8), you will need to configure the `<repository>` on your Maven POM and then add the dependency as shown above.

Alternatively, you can download the JAR file directly from [SpringSource](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.javax.annotation&version=1.0.0).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Which one do you think is correct?  I get a 404 on `http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external` and `http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release`

Comment: You're right. I can't help further since I don't know which link exists anymore.